# Is there a way to sense all collisions except the one selected?

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I want to detect a collision, which is easy enough, except I need to basically have an exception. I want to do something like this:

[image: NotWater]

What I am trying to do is detect all collisions except those with the property `water`.Is there an easy way to do this? Or a hard way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is super easy to do *logically*.

You want the controller (in this case it is an **and** controller) to send a positive pulse to the actuator(s) when the the cube collides with anything *Except* for the objects with the property **Water**.

[image]

The first collision sensor is always true as long as the cube is not colliding with **Water**. True level triggering is enabled, so every logic tick the **and** controller gets a positive pulse. however, for the actuator to receive the pulse, *all* sensors must be true, at the same time.

The second collision sensor detects a collision with anything.

With this setup, a collision with water obviously will not work because the first collision sensor will not be true when colliding with water. When the cube is falling or hovering, (not colliding with anything) the first collision sensor will be true, because the cube is not colliding with water, but the second will not be true.

Comment: [True level triggering] triggers connected controllers unnecessary = not needed. Just enable [Pulse] at the unfiltered collision sensor (the second one) to get a trigger for each newly detected object. In case of Python or Expression controllers you HAVE to check the status of BOTH sensors.

Comment: Good points, I hadn't though of that.